# hide next button when last element reaches

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a simple gallery with an `overlay` to display enlarged image when clicked.

In my gallery, every 3 images are grouped into a container as

```
<div class='overlay'>
  <a class='next control'>Next</a>
</div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100&text=Image1"/>
    </div>
    <div class="image">
      <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100&text=Image2" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
      <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100&text=Image3"/>
    </div>
</div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100&text=Image4"/>
    </div>
    <div class="image">
      <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100&text=Image5" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
      <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100&text=Image6"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var src;
    var currentElement;
    $(".image").click(function () {
        currentElement = $(this);
        src = $(currentElement).find("img").attr("src");
        $(".overlay").css("background-image", "url('" + src + "')");
        $(".overlay").show();
    });
    $(".next").click(function () {
        if ($(currentElement).next().length) {
            currentElement = currentElement.next();
            src = $(currentElement).find("img").attr("src");
        }
        else {
            currentElement = $(currentElement).parent().next().find(".image:first");
            src = $(currentElement).find("img").attr("src");
        }
        $(".overlay").css("background-image", "url('" + src + "')");
    });
});
```

I am able to get the next image on clicking next. But my problem is **How to disable the next button when last image reaches ?**.

I am unable to find a logic to get the last image.

Note: the images in last container may vary from 1 to 3

Here is the demo : https://jsfiddle.net/y5fwgz25/1/

Comment: can you use data attribute on your code? if yes you can use an attribute for you last image, and ....

Comment: The images are displayed from a database using asp.net listview. And the no. of images may vary as new records are inserted or deleted from db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is my solution but i do not like this code, but works fine

```
<div class='overlay'>
  <a class='next'></a>
</div>
<div id="gallery">
<div class="container">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100&text=Image1"/>
    </div>
    <div class="image">
      <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100&text=Image2" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
      <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100&text=Image3"/>
    </div>
</div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100&text=Image4"/>
    </div>
    <div class="image">
      <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100&text=Image5" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
      <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100&text=Image6"/>
    </div>
</div>

</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
  var src;
  var currentElement;
  var last_img = $("#gallery .container:last-child .image:last-child");
  $(".image").click(function () {
    currentElement = $(this);
    src = $(currentElement).find("img").attr("src");
    $(".overlay").css("background-image", "url('" + src + "')");
    $(".overlay").show();

    if ( $(currentElement)[0] == $(last_img)[0] ) {
      $(".overlay .next").hide();
    }

  });


  $(".next").click(function () {

    if ( $(currentElement).next()[0] == $(last_img)[0] ) {
      $(".overlay .next").hide();
    }

    if ($(currentElement).next().length) {
      currentElement = currentElement.next();
      src = $(currentElement).find("img").attr("src");
    }else {
      currentElement = $(currentElement).parent().next().find(".image:first");
      src = $(currentElement).find("img").attr("src");
    }



    $(".overlay").css("background-image", "url('" + src + "')");
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks works fine. Can you explain why you didn't like the code ?

Comment: @Munawir the only part i don't like is  ` $(currentElement)[0] == $(last_img)[0] ` but on the other hand you say, you do not have access to print images clean, so this type of coding maybe the only solution.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use jquery last method to get the last sibling and compare any of its attributes with the same attributes of the current element. 
If they are the same, hide or disable the next button.

Answer (score 0):

You can add one `if` condition. If the length of `currentElement` is zero then hide `.next`.

Updated Fiddle-

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 var src;
 var currentElement;
 $(".image").click(function () {
  currentElement = $(this);
  src = $(currentElement).find("img").attr("src");
  $(".overlay").css("background-image", "url('" + src + "')");
  $(".overlay").show();
 });
 $(".next").click(function () {
  if ($(currentElement).next().length) {
   currentElement = currentElement.next();
   src = $(currentElement).find("img").attr("src");
  }
  else {
   currentElement = $(currentElement).parent().next().find(".image:first");
   src = $(currentElement).find("img").attr("src");
  }
    if($(currentElement).length==0) {
        $(".next").hide();
    }
  $(".overlay").css("background-image", "url('" + src + "')");
 });
});
```

```css
.overlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9) no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}
.next {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    top: 50%;
    background-image: url("http://dummyimage.com/50&text=Next");
    right: 8em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='overlay'>
  <a class='next'></a>
</div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100&text=Image1"/>
    </div>
    <div class="image">
      <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100&text=Image2" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
      <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100&text=Image3"/>
    </div>
</div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100&text=Image4"/>
    </div>
    <div class="image">
      <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100&text=Image5" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
      <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100&text=Image6"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That works only when the next button from last image is clicked. I need to hide the next button when Image6 is shown

Comment: Okay, so image6 will be there but no next button?

Comment: Yes, the Image6 should be displayed with no next button.